# Bootstrap text fields have suddenly shrunk

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, doctype, gemfile

Evening all,

I have a site which uses twitter bootstrap, with the same CSS styles as a previous site so i am familiar with how things should look.

I ran bundle update, and suddenly all of the text fields, not areas, have shrunk in height, and no matter what CSS i code, i can't touch them. Also the logo has drifted to the left of the page.

Many similar questions suggest changing the DOCTYPE which i have tried to no avail.

CSS code for forms as follows;

```
input, textarea, select, .uneditable-input {
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  @include box_sizing;
}
```

text fields being used as follows, which worked beforehand;

```
<div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
    <%= f.text_field :song_name, placeholder: "please enter a song title..." %>
        <br />
    <%= f.text_area :song, placeholder: "enter music score..." %>
        </div>
    </div>
```

gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.5'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
end


group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '1.4.0'
gem 'koala'
```

if you need more code just ask, but any thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Cheers Andy

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your server and held shift while clicking refresh? Sounds like a caching issue here...

Comment: Hi Sgrif unfortunately it hasn't done anything, i manually emptied the cache as well

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this sorted in a slightly unusual way.

When i updated the twitter bootstrap rails gem, it updates the bootstrap overides and css file, adding in some extra imports. Deleting this file completely solved everything.

Im not so sure this is the correct solution but it certainly sorted things my end. –